# Can not make vertical scroll work on canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to place for example 20 text boxes in a Canvas. So my widget hierarchy is main window -> canvas -> text boxes. The text boxes can not fit all in the canvas, so I want to attach a vertical scroll bar to it. Here is what I've tried:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (root_width, root_height))

canvas = Canvas(root, height=root_height, width=root_width)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(canvas)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

textBoxes = []

for i in range(0, 20):
    textBoxes.append(Text(canvas, height=1, width=20, bd=2))

y_offset = 15
for i in range(0, 20):
    textBoxes[i].place(x=10, y=y_offset)
    y_offset += 60

scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)


mainloop()
```

So basically, I tried to do what I've understood from tutorials and other questions -

1. Set the widget’s(canvas) `yscrollcommand` callbacks to the set method of the scrollbar.
2. Set the scrollbar’s command to the `yview` method of the widget(canvas).

Unfortunately the scrollbar appears unclickable. Where I am wrong and how can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a separate `Frame` widget that contains all the `Text` objects. Then in `Canvas` make a call to the `.create_window` method setting `Frame` as the `window` argument.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
root_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

frame = Frame(canvas)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

def resize(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor=NW)

canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
frame.bind('<Configure>', resize)

for i in range(20):
    text = Text(frame, width=30, height=1)
    text.grid(row=i, pady=i*10)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrollbars only scroll canvas objects. It will not scroll widgets added inside the canvas with `pack`, `place` or `grid`. For a widget to be scrollable it must be added with `canvas.create_window(...)`.

Comment: could you please help me more with a modified example of my code?